# Blender rendered shows wrong placement of textures but according to UV map they are correct

Tags: rendering, texturing

So, I wanted to Color a Building and the top worked out perfect but now on the main part It Shows the three marked Long faces as blue (Right part of the texture and the black-grey upper face as black-grey, although as seen in the UV map they are supposed to be correctly placed, what is wrong out of a sudden?

[image: That is wrong]

Comment: May be you have multiple UVMaps.

Comment: Well I actually have but None of the faces is unpcked in any other UV map. I fixed it though, just made another UV map and treated them as new UV mesh